# Moving a custom ViewCell renderer from Xamarin to MAUI

Tags: .net-6.0, maui

In *XAMARIN FORMS* I used a custom renderer to change the background color of a selected item in a `ListView` and the default background color, but I was having a hard time modifying my app in MAUI to accomplish the same thing.

**XAML**:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          HorizontalOptions="Start">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <custom:CustomViewCell SelectedItemBackgroundColor="#00552E">
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Label Text="{Binding LabelText}" FontSize="20" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </custom:CustomViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and it worked with a **CustomRenderer**

```
using Foundation;
using MyApp;
using MyApp.iOS;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

///Custom Renderer for the ListView on iOS
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomViewCell), typeof(CustomViewCellRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    
    public class CustomViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            
            cell.SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView
            {
                BackgroundColor = view.SelectedItemBackgroundColor.ToUIColor(),
            };
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

But in MAUI instead of showing the Binding LabelText, its showing each cell's text as:

> namespace.CustomViewCell

when rendered, I know its something I'm doing wrong in the Handler because if I remove the handler from MauiProgram `.ConfigureMauiHandlers` the text is then displayed properly but then I have the wrong background color. If anyone can help me to understand what I'm missing in my custom handler, I'd appreciate it.

I used this source for how to implement the custom handler:
[handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-8.0)

**ListView.ItemsSource**

```
new ObservableCollection<NavMenuItem>
{
        new NavMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Welcome, LabelText="Home" },
        new NavMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Bonus, LabelText="Bonus" },
        new NavMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.FourO1k, LabelText="401k" },
        new NavMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.CallSheet, LabelText="Call Sheet" }
};
```

**NavMenuItem**

```
public class NavMenuItem
{
    public MenuItemType Id { get; set; }

    public string LabelText { get; set; }
}

public enum MenuItemType
{
    ....
}
```

**CustomViewCell**:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

public class CustomViewCell : ViewCell
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemBackgroundColorProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create("SelectedItemBackgroundColor", typeof(Color), 
            typeof(CustomViewCell), Color.FromRgb(0, 86, 47));

    public Color SelectedItemBackgroundColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(SelectedItemBackgroundColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedItemBackgroundColorProperty, value);
    }
}
```

**iOS Handler**:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility;

partial class CustomViewCellHandler : CellRenderer
{
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
        cell.SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView()
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(((CustomViewCell)item).SelectedItemBackgroundColor.Red,
            ((CustomViewCell)item).SelectedItemBackgroundColor.Green, ((CustomViewCell)item).SelectedItemBackgroundColor.Blue),
        };

        return cell;
    }

}
```

MAUI Project Handler is just an empty partial, perhaps I am missing something with the Mappings??:

```
partial class CustomViewCellHandler
{       
}
```

**MauiProgram.cs**

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .UseMauiCompatibility()
        .ConfigureMauiHandlers(h =>
        {
        #if IOS
            h.AddHandler(typeof(CustomViewCell), typeof(namespace.Platforms.iOS.Handlers.CustomViewCellHandler));
        #endif
        })
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        });

    
    return builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: I don't really know MAUI, but empty partial classes are there so that source generators can kick in. Not sure if the class needs to be public, but it's worth a try. Plus, you can inspect generated code and see if there is anything at all - if not, you are missings ome configuration

Comment: yeah, so you as a programmer create an empty partial class/partial method, and source generator generates another partial implementation.  Maybe you need some marker attribute for the generator to know to take this class into consideration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many attempts to find the error in my code above, I ended up scrapping my attempt at using a custom handler, and instead used the static `Mapper` of the `CellRenderer`. Using the following to make things work:

In `Platforms.iOS` in my `AppDelegate.cs` `FinishedLaunching` method:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.CellRenderer.Mapper.AppendToMapping("CustomBackground",
    (renderer, cell) =>
    {
        if(cell is CustomViewCell)
        {
           UITableViewCell c = renderer.PlatformView;
           c.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
           c.SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView
           {
              BackgroundColor = 
              ((CustomViewCell)cell).SelectedItemBackgroundColor.ToPlatform()
           };
        }             
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this to change selected item's color. Add this end of data template.

```
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Aqua" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: I did too, but when the `ListView` is in a flyout page, it doesn't retain the selected background color when the flyout page opens again. In my case, the flyout page is a ListView of Menu items.

Comment: Can you change listview to Collectionview ?

Comment: Tried that too, didn't work for my use case.

Comment: This is so simple in xamarin forms but your effort is so much. I think you can find a simple way.

Comment: I gave you an upvote for the `VisualStateGroup` suggestion, which if this page was not a flyout, would be a good way to do it.